# BlackBerry Connection Transport Descriptors

Tags: blackberry

I'm wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for this problem. A bit of introduction:

In an app we maintan we just rewrote our network layer to remove support for OS 4. We're using the cleaner `ConnectionFactory` provided in OS 5. Please note the issues we're encountering are device-only, not simulator related.

There are two ways or app has connectivity, a data thread that polls specific urls and stores data, and a "generic web view" (a `BrowserField`).

So far it seems there's no problems with the data thread connectivity, it properly builds the urls based off transport type and downloads the data correctly. In the `BrowserField` we have a different problem. There's an OS 6 curve causing problems (no other OS 6 device though) when we open the `BrowserField` with a URL there's a chance it will show a "Could not select proper transport descriptor" message - the most common culprit is WAP2.

I guess we're a bit baffled that BlackBerry doesn't seem to handle the transport descriptor choosing as well as we had hoped. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Due to its length, I've posted our connection utility class on gist: https://gist.github.com/3490101

The most common connection form, used by the data thread, is the `getUrlAsString(String etag)` function, which does a GET and caches the response based off the etag/url.

To build URLs for our `BrowserField` we use the `buildURLTransport(String url)` function, which gets a connection on the url, determines the transport information, and returns the built URL.

**TL;DR:** There's an oddity in a `BrowserField` we can't seem to debug, we'd appreciate a new set of eyes: we think there's something wrong in the above posted gist in the `buildURLTransport(String url)` function.

Thanks a tonne in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful with your code because `getUrlAsString` isn't thread safe. I didn't understand why you keep reference to the `ConnectionFactory` sometimes why you don't for other.

I aslo didn't understand why do you need method `buildUrlTransport`. Why don't use `BrowserFieldConfig` together with `ConnectionFactory` for `BrowserField` as [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-Code-Using-the-ConnectionFactory-class-in-a-BrowserField/ta-p/532860).

So I would instantiate one `ConnectionFactory`, configure it with your specific parameters and use it everywhere. In case of preferences change I would recreate `ConnectionFactory` and update `BrowserFieldConfig`. Sure this code should be thread safe.

Also be more consistent - sometimes you use quick connection check, sometimes you don't.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go over this tomorrow and post adjustments (will accept answer then). Thanks for the cleanup suggestions! By configuration change do you mean if the device's connectivity has changed? Example: if WiFi becomes unavailable and switches to MDS, would a new connection factory be needed, or would the held reference just retry until an available transport is found?

Comment: I see that you set preferable transports from your settings. You could set list of them like {WiFi, BIS-B, MDS, WAP2, DirectTCP}. In this case you don't need to configure anything ConnectionFactory should do job about switching itself.

Comment: Agree with the answer. However, sometimes `ConnectionFactory` transport type selection doesn't work as expected, in particular with partially configured Wi-Fi networks.

Comment: @MisterSmith I didn't find solution for this yet. I was thinking about hotspot API or try to open connection with some short timeout first.

Comment: @Eugen Martinov. I usually have an initial array of preferred transport types, but before making a connection, I check each element in the array (`TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable && TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage`). Elements that pass the test are saved to a second array, which is the one I set to the factory as actual preferred transport types. It would have been nice if the factory were able to do this for me.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, refactoring and adding the connection factory to the BrowserField fixed the problem!